# Python: modifier_apply() only works with first occurrence in loop

Tags: python, modifiers

I applied a bevel effect on many cubes with a loop like this:

```
for cube in bpy.data.collections['Cubes'].objects:
  cube.modifiers.new(name="Bevel", type='BEVEL')
  cube.modifiers['Bevel'].segments = 2
  bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(
    modifier=cube.modifiers['Bevel'].name
  )
```

But `modifier_apply()` only works on the first occurrence. I'm getting this:

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=bpy.data.collections['Cubes'].objects['2'].modifiers['Bevel'].name)
{'FINISHED'}

>>> bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=bpy.data.collections['Cubes'].objects['3'].modifiers['Bevel'].name)
{'CANCELLED'}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `modifier_apply` to work for every object, you have to first set the object as active using `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = cube`

This code will work:

```
import bpy

for cube in bpy.data.collections['Cubes'].objects:
    cube.modifiers.new(name="Bevel", type='BEVEL')
    cube.modifiers['Bevel'].segments = 2
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = cube
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=cube.modifiers['Bevel'].name)
```